# Using postman to login into a website configured to using Azure AD (SAML)

Tags: azure-active-directory, postman, saml-2.0

We currently have a website that is setup to use SSO through Azure AD. it is configured to with SAML.

Yet, we have third application that needs to connect to this website using specific email and password.

This application can do any default connection that POSTMAN can do.

What I do notice is that web all cookies are removed from the browser. the website allows me to enter
the email address and password.

[image]

I am trying to configure POSTMAN to test login to this website. And using the POSTMAN configuration i will be able to configure the application.

Any Guidance is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have try configuring post using HTTPS POST BASIC Authentication. Not sure if this correct manner as I am not postman expert nor have attempted such authentication method before.

Our expectation is the POSTMAN could login into the website and create a cookie that has an active session.

Answer (score 0):

Postman is not a browser so it doesn't "log in". The authentication in Postman is related to webservice calls. So imagine you have an online shop and you expose your API to a third party (let's say a sponsor or partner). For example you let another site (the partner/sponsor) add items for your common client from his site (instead of him having to logout of that site then login to your site, it's easier and your partnership makes both sites profitable, let's say for our example - so their site would be more like a sort of forwarder - when the user adds an item on the partner's site, they actually add it in the cart on your site).

In our example, they would call your API (for example, adding an item in the cart). The question is, how do they do that? How do you stop abuse from a malicious user? Simple: you add authentication. So what your (theoretical) shop's partner does is use some auth method (as you said, Basic Auth) to call the endpoint that results into adding an item into the cart for purchase.

But this auth is not what the client uses to log in to your partner or your site. It's an internal auth, like a sort of a "technical" user. And what you would do in Postman is simulate that call and the Postman login would be to allow it to call endpoints.

If, on the other hand, you have a separate login call that this is all it does, logging in, then yes, you can use Postman to login, BUT, keep in mind that the login auth info would not **AND SHOULD NOT** be the same as the API call login info. So you would still use an auth to allow the API call and a (hopefully different) auth for the actual login url as params.

In other words, Postman auth in any POST or GET call is just a way to tell the remote server they can trust you because you identify yourself. A login window like the Microsoft one is one for user accounts which is something totally different.

Comment: understood, prior to upgrading this website with azure AD SSO. we did have that login in which passed URL along with user credential parameters which now have changed. this website does not allow for application type logins. A specific user and password must be entered which then authenticates using Azure AD and allowing entry to website as that user. Can postman be configured to Authenticate by using the same to Azure Endpoint which the website uses or can something like client authentication certificate be used to accomplish authentication from third party like POSTMAN?

Comment: I am not sure if the technical user can belong to the AD. If it can, best practice is to separate the AD group and properties of the regular users that access the site, from the technical users that do API calls. As I said, if you want to test the login call, Postman can do that and simulate what the user does on the browser page in theory, but you would still need a technical user to make that call. But it's a bit unclear to me, why do you need to simulate user login from Postman? The browser should be enough to test AD access or SSO (almost) persistent sessions. You can use incognito mode.

Comment: yes, the service account is part of separate group in AD which has access to the site. I am able to login as the service account via browser. I would like to use postman is to test it and then configure the application that uses the service account to run automated jobs. exactly how that would be configured for a site that uses sso through saml is what i need help with.  if you can share any links or configuration that seen or done in this scenario is great appreciated.